# Oracle query in R using binds

Tags: r, oracle, bind, roracle

I am using the library **ROracle** and I need to execute a query using binds. However, I'm getting the error below:

> Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 2

```
    sql <- paste("SELECT COD_STORE
               FROM  TBL_STORES 
               WHERE COD_STORE = :codStore 
               AND COD_REGION = :codRegion")

  #codLoja <- 1
  #codRegional <- 243

  r <- dbGetQuery(conn, sql, data=data.frame(codStore = 1, codRegion = 243))
```

Comment: a work around: `sql <- paste0("SELECT COD_STORE FROM  TBL_STORES WHERE COD_STORE = '",codStore ,
              "' AND COD_REGION = '",codRegion,"'")`

Comment: But using this workaround we will lose the perfomance improvement of the bind, won't we?